# Having two matrices which are changed at each iteration, can i show these changes in an animated way?(python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import xor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=input('Give the number of rows ')
j=input('Give the number of columns ')
k=input('Give number of iterations ')
M=np.random.randint(2,size=(i, j))
N=np.random.randint(2,size=(i, j))
print('Initial matrix:')
print(M)
for z in range(k):
    for x in range(i):
        if((z%2)==0):
            for y in range(j):
                if(y==0):
                    if(M.item(x,y+1)==0):
                        N[x][y]=0
                    else:
                        N[x][y]=1
                elif(y==(j-1)):
                    if(M.item(x,y-1)==0):
                        N[x][y]=0
                    else:
                        N[x][y]=1
                else:
                    N[x][y]=xor(M[x][y-1],M[x][y+1])
        else:
            for y in range(j):
                if(y==0):
                    if(N.item(x,y+1)==0):
                        M[x][y]=0
                    else:
                        M[x][y]=1
                elif(y==(j-1)):
                    if(N.item(x,y-1)==0):
                        M[x][y]=0
                    else:
                        M[x][y]=1
                else:
                    M[x][y]=xor(N[x][y-1],N[x][y+1])
if((k%2)==0): 
    print('Matrix after processing:')
    print(M)
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.imshow(M, cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
else:
    print('Matrix after processing:')
    print(N)
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.imshow(N, cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
```

This is my version of rule 90(I won't speak about it 'cause it doesn't matter for my question). I create 2 matrices and change them while iterating(at odd iterations is changed one but at even other). I just want to show how my matrix is changed. I tried to find it by myself but failed.It will be coll if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1):

The error you should have caught is that the if-statements you plot in are all the way to the left, so *not* part of the indented loop, so they only ran once. You should also look up the difference between an axis and a figure and the current axis in matplotlib, which I have put into a little function to do the repetitive stuff.

```
import numpy as np
from operator import xor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotMN(M, N, describe):
    fig = plt.figure()
    Max = fig.add_subplot(121)
    print(describe)
    #print(M)
    plt.imshow(M, cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest')
    Nax = fig.add_subplot(122)
    plt.imshow(N, cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
    plt.close()



i=input('Give the number of rows ')
j=input('Give the number of columns ')
k=input('Give number of iterations ')
M=np.random.randint(2,size=(i, j))
N=np.random.randint(2,size=(i, j))
plotMN(M, N, 'Initial matrices M, N:')

for z in range(k):
    for x in range(i):
        if((z%2)==0):
            for y in range(j):
                if(y==0):
                    if(M.item(x,y+1)==0):
                        N[x][y]=0
                    else:
                        N[x][y]=1
                elif(y==(j-1)):
                    if(M.item(x,y-1)==0):
                        N[x][y]=0
                    else:
                        N[x][y]=1
                else:
                    N[x][y]=xor(M[x][y-1],M[x][y+1])
        else:
            for y in range(j):
                if(y==0):
                    if(N.item(x,y+1)==0):
                        M[x][y]=0
                    else:
                        M[x][y]=1
                elif(y==(j-1)):
                    if(N.item(x,y-1)==0):
                        M[x][y]=0
                    else:
                        M[x][y]=1
                else:
                    M[x][y]=xor(N[x][y-1],N[x][y+1])

    plotMN(M, N, 'M, N after %d iterations'%z)
```